# Views not rendering, Regions vs. Layouts

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm still a bit confused even after reading the wiki and examples as to when to use layouts vs regions, etc, but my problem is I can't get anything to show up on the page - nothing renders at all. The html should really only have a menu and content, and the content can be changed based on Views. (I did the menu the same way so I can swap that as well).

I have an html file:

```
<!-- DefaultLayout -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-default">
   <div id="region-navbar">
     region-navbar
   </div>
   <div id="region-content">
      region-content
   </div>
</script>

<!-- NavBar -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-navbar">
   <div id="navbar">
      my freakin navbar
   </div>
</script>

<!-- ViewOne -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-view1">
   <div id="view1">
      my freakin view
   </div>
</script>

<!-- RegionContainer -->
<div id="default-layout-container">
</div>
```

I've condensed the js to a single file for this example, **app.coffee**:

```
window.App = { }

# Region
class RegionContainer extends Backbone.Marionette.Region
  el: '#default-layout-container'   
  # Called on the region when the view has been rendered
  onShow: (view) ->
    console.log 'onShow RegionContainer'

App.RegionContainer = RegionContainer

# Layout
class DefaultLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
  template: '#template-default'  
  regions:
    navbarRegion: '#region-navbar'
    contentRegion: '#region-content'

App.DefaultLayout = DefaultLayout

# NavBar (View)
class NavBar extends Backbone.View
  el: '#template-navbar'    
  initialize: () ->
    console.log 'init App.NavBar'

App.NavBar = NavBar

# A View
class ViewOne extends Backbone.View
  el: '#template-view1'  
  initialize: () ->
    console.log 'init App.ViewOne'

App.ViewOne = ViewOne

# App
$ ->

  # Create application, allow for global access
  MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application()
  App.MyApp = MyApp

  # On application init...
  MyApp.addInitializer (data) ->
    console.log 'init App.MyApp'

  # RegionContainer
  regionContainer = new App.RegionContainer

  # Layout (holds Views)
  defaultLayout = new App.DefaultLayout
  regionContainer.show defaultLayout

  # Views
  navBarView = new App.NavBar
  navBarView.render()

  viewOne = new App.ViewOne
  viewOne.render()

  defaultLayout.navbarRegion.show navBarView
  defaultLayout.contentRegion.show viewOne

  data = 
    that: 'this'

  MyApp.start data
```

The console.log shows:

```
onShow RegionContainer app.js:19
init App.NavBar app.js:44
init App.ViewOne 
init App.MyApp
```

I've read the docs/examples a million times, but the learning curve of all these things is compounded. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing a few thing but you are almost there

- `ViewOne` and `NavBar` should not extend `Backbone.View` but `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView`
- you should not define the template for `ViewOne` and `NavBar` in the `el` attribute, but, as the name suggests, in the `template` attribute.

Comment: additionally, no need to call navBarView.render() and viewOne.render() explicitely.